# driver cannot be resolved when running using TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

```
  package bannerTstNG;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    public class BannerTestNG {
        
        
        @BeforeTest
        public void OpenTheSuperAdmin() throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\myselenium\\bannerTstNG\\driver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://ss-superadmin-staging.labaiik.net/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("arsalan.hameed@avrioc.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("admin");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        }
    
        @Test
        public void ClickOnBanner() {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[4]/a[1]")).click
        
        }   
    }
```

The function `OpenTheSuperAdmin()` is running but when `ClickOnBanner()` is executed, I get the following error: `driver cannot be resolved.`

Why is `OpenTheSuperAdmin()` being executed without any errors and the driver error not showing there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating the `driver` variable inside of the `OpenTheSuperAdmin` method so it is outside of the scope of the `ClickOnBanner` test. Please try the following:

```
    package bannerTstNG;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    public class BannerTestNG {

        private WebDriver driver;        
        
        @BeforeTest
        public void OpenTheSuperAdmin() throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\myselenium\\bannerTstNG\\driver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

            driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.get("https://ss-superadmin-staging.labaiik.net/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("arsalan.hameed@avrioc.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("admin");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        }
    
        @Test
        public void ClickOnBanner() {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[4]/a[1]")).click
        
        }
    }
```

By declaring the driver as a field in the class you will now be able to access it from any of the tests inside of the class.

Comment: Thank You It's working very thankful to you.